# Why am I losing the two decimal points in this cast expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What am I missing here?

```
select cast ( ( cast (100 * 39  as decimal )  / 41) as decimal(5,2))
```

gives a result of 95.12

but

```
declare @percent decimal 
set  @percent = cast ( ( cast (100 * 39  as decimal )  / 41)  as decimal(5,2)) 
select @percent
```

gives a result of 95

What happened to the two 2 decimal points and how do I get them back into my variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DECIMAL` on its own does not have any decimal places (it's actually `DECIMAL(18,0)`). You need to specify precision and scale, e.g.

```
DECLARE @percent DECIMAL(5,2);
SET @percent = 1.0 * (100 * 39) / 41;
SELECT @percent;
```

Comment: Duh! Of course. I will choose this as my answer as soon as I am allowed to. Thanks!!